# Не работает InputListener в классе актера - Actor

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Никак не могу понять в чем может быть дело.

1. Есть актер:

   ```
   public class Quard extends Actor {

   Sprite sprite;
   private static float x, y = 0;

   public Quard() {

       sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("quard.png")));
       this.addListener(new InputListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float screenX, float screenY, int pointer, int button) {

               x = screenX;
               y = screenY;

               Gdx.app.log("tag", "touchDown");

               return true;
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

       sprite.setPosition(x, y);
       sprite.draw(batch);

   }
   ```

   }
2. Есть вызывающий экран, где в методе show() создается Stage и данный актер:

   ```
       @Override
   public void show() {

       camera = new OrthographicCamera();
       camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 0);
       viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);

       //Создаем первого Актера
       image = new Image(new NinePatch(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("fon.png"))));
       image.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

       //Создаем второго актера
       quard = new Quard();

       stage = new Stage(viewport);
       stage.addActor(image);
       stage.addActor(quard);

       quard.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
       image.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

       Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
   }
   ```

Проблема в том, что не срабатывает метод `touchDown`. В чем проблема? Никак не могу разобраться. Google такую проблему знает, но решается она (то что я нашел) добавлением `setInputProcessor`.

PS. Пробовал в `setInputProcessor` подставить собственно написанный `InputProcessor` - все работает отлично.

Comment: Может быть Вы не вызываете stage.act() в render?

Comment: К сожалению вызываю :(

Comment: Кажется я понял в чем дело. Вы не установили границы актера через setBounds(float x, float y, float width, float height).

Comment: Точно! Все заработало. Действительно, надо было только добавить `quard.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());` Спасибо вам большое!